# Is it possible to use internal values in a public enum C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I am using a public enum (say, **Days**) where I need to use one value (say, **Sunday**) as private (or) internal. But the below code fails.

```
 public enum Days
    {
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday,
        internal Sunday
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve the requirement in c#?

Comment: No. You could use a struct with `static readonly` members (aka a "java-style" or "smart" enum) instead

Comment: `internal` to that declaration would not be very useful

Comment: Of course, from a SR perspective, this is a code smell to even **want** to.

Comment: No sense to hide that. Domain model should be split from public api.
Declare 2 separate enums and convert from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: yes, but not with enums in c#. You'd need a POCO, or a struct, or something similar. Enums in C# aren't meant to be used like that.